# Groovy get deeply nested parameter from Jenkins XML

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have an XML file in Jenkins that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<build>
  <actions>
    <hudson.model.ParametersAction>
      <safeParameters class="sorted-set"/>
      <parameters class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
        <a class="hudson.model.ParameterValue-array">
          <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
            <name>branch</name>
            <description></description>
            <value>feature/MyAmazingBranch</value>
          </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          ...
</build>
```

I am aiming to build a gradle task that will return the branch parameter, in this case `feature/MyAmazingBranch`.

I have been able to parse the XML, and print the parsed result, but it doesn't currently make sense to me, and I'm not sure how to access a specific node.

```
task getBranch {
    ext.srcFile = file('build_jenkins.xml')
    def buildFile = new XmlParser().parse(srcFile)

    println buildFile

}
```

This prints:

```
build[attributes={}; value=[actions[attributes={}; value=[hudson.model.ParametersAction[attributes={}; value=[safeParameters[attributes={class=sorted-set}; value=[]], parameters[attributes={class=java.util.Arrays$ArrayList}; value=[a[attributes={class=hudson.model.ParameterValue-array}; value=[hudson.model.StringParameterValue[attributes={}; value=[name[attributes={}; value=[branch]], description[attributes={}; value=[]], value[attributes={}; value=[feature/WAWEB-6358-create-api-for-developer-applications]]]]....
```

How would I go about accessing the parameter names and values using Gradle/Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

The following will create you a collection of values for children with parent nodes prefixed with `hudson.model.` & suffixed with `ParameterValue` with something in the middle of this which seems to be the pattern for subclasses of [hudson.model.ParameterValue](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParameterValue.html)

```
def build = new XmlSlurper().parse( srcFile )
def params = build.'**'.findAll{ node -> node.name() =~ /hudson.model.[\w.]+ParameterValue/ }*.value
```